# What is the salesforce equivalent of Microsoft's Northwind database

Tags: unit-test, database

This sounds like an obvious question but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere.

Does Salesforce have an equivalent of Microsoft's Northwind database?

My problem is that I have gone through the fantastic introductory guides on the developer site, however after building by own data structures, I am unsure as to how representative these would be of real companies' databases.

Is there a test database which developers typically link to when developing, which have the basic structure of a small or medium sized company's Salesforce database?

Comment: I've never thought about this personally, but it's a good question and definitely *not* obvious. Salesforce does come with some records by default when you create a new org, but it's not exactly a Northwind database.

Comment: A new Developer Edition org comes with some sample data, but it is NOT representative of a real customer. I think developers are largely on their own to create sample data.